# Flutter no state changes when using Navigator.of(context).push(..) in a GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a product store right now. I have a product Card which is using a GestureDetector to navigate to the SingleProductPage. In my SingleProductPage I am using a callback function to add/remove this product as a favorite. When using one of these Callback function, my Stateful Widget will change the state to the new favorite product list. But for some reason, my SingleProductPage doesn't get the new state and the page wont rebuild. All other widgets are getting rebuilded when changing the state.

This is my GestureDestectore in the product card:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => SingleProductPage(product, account, favorites,
                  addFavoriteCallback, removeFavoriteCallback)));
        },
```

This is what my favorite button does on remove favorite:

```
    if(favoriteId != null) {
       removeFavoriteCallback(favoriteId);
    }
```

And this is what happens when the removeFavoriteCallback gets executed:

```
void onRemoveFavorite(int favoriteId) {
    if (_userAccount != null) {
      favoriteService
          .deleteFavorite(
              FavoriteDeleteRequest(_userAccount!.userId, favoriteId))
          .then((value) => getFavoritesByUser());
    }
  }

  void getFavoritesByUser() {
    if (_userAccount != null) {
      favoriteService.getFavoritesByUser(_userAccount!.userId).then((value) => {
            if (value != null)
              {
                setState(() {
                  _favorites = Favorites(value.products);
                })
              }
          });
    }
  }
```

Comment: if you didnt use any state management, then you have to call `setState` in every function get called

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you call a function that has `setState()` in it, which updates the widget function is called from(which is product card in your example), simple solution would be to wrap in `setState()` as well

```
if(favoriteId != null) {
    setState(() =>removeFavoriteCallback(favoriteId));
}
```

so you update your single card widget

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't use the setState() function in the SingleProductPage, because its a StatelessWidget. Or is the a smart way to do it?

Comment: You have to either make it stageful and call setState() or make some provider for it and listen to its changes, I recommend using https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Is this really the only possible way? I don't get it. Why I cant share my state through pages by using a Navigator?

Comment: You can share it, but you need to notify your Stateless widget that state has changed and it needs to be rebuild. And since it is a new route for you Stateless widget it won't rebuild if you stageful widget before changes